# Pointers to quick start/cheat sheet guides for Cocoa/Mac programmers who want to start developing for Cocoa Touch/iOS?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios

For someone who has read Hillegass's Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X and has developed OS X software for a little over a year, is there a succinct guide to transferring those skills to jump-start iOS development? What I mean, instead of buying How to Develop iPhone Applications or other iOS-centric books, is there a simple, quick-read guide that shows the similarities and differences between Cocoa and Cocoa-Touch in code and in XCode/IB usage as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Introduction to the Foundation Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/ObjC_classic/Intro/IntroFoundation.html) covers that section of the intersection.

I don't know what to suggest for UIKit, except for the following tidbit: UITableView and UITableViewCell are *totally different* from NSTableView and the NSCell hierarchy.